# mysql-display different columns from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

Consider the following table and values..i need to display all the column and its values from table "TAG" along with single column value from another table named as "ITEM"

TABLE NAME "TAG"

```
TAGID   NAME    RATE    
1   A   100
2   B   200
3   C   300
4   D   8099
5   E   400
6   F   500
7   G   600
8   H   700
9   I   200
10  J   400
```

TABLE NAME "ITEM"

```
ITEMID  Name    ITEM_QTY    
1   A   11
2   B   22
3   I   3
4   A   8
5   B   42
6   C   5
7   I   61
8   B   74
9   C   99
10  A   48
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
TAGID   NAME    RATE    ITEM_QTY
1   A   100 48  - (VALUE OF LAST INSERTED RECORD)
2   B   200 74
3   C   300 99
4   D   8099    0
5   E   400 0
6   F   500 0
7   G   600 0
8   H   700 0
9   I   200 61
10  J   400 0
```

i have tried some sort of quires  but its all vien..

this is my query,

```
select *
  from tag t1
  join ( select item_qty
           from item t2
          join tag t1
    on t1.name=t2.name;
```

can anyone pls help me out of this issue...

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
select tag.id,tag.name,rate,qty from tag join 
 (select qty,name from
ITEM where ITEM.id in 
(select max(id) from ITEM group by name)) as tt on tt.name=tag.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try as

```
select
t.tagid,
t.name,
t.rate,
i.item_qty
from tag t
join
(
  select name,max(item_qty) as item_qty
  from item group by name

)i
on i.name = t.name
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43274/1)**

If you need all the data from item table as you have shown in the output you may use left join instead of inner join

```
select
t.tagid,
t.name,
t.rate,
coalesce(i.item_qty,0) as item_qty 
from tag t
left join
(
  select name,max(item_qty) as item_qty
  from item group by name

)i
on i.name = t.name
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35c35d/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that the last inserted record has the highest ID in your item table, you first need to get the highest ID per item name.

```
SELECT
Name, MAX(ITEMID) AS max_id
FROM 
item
GROUP BY Name;
```

With this query (executed in the following query as subquery) we get the corresponding row for each max_id.

```
SELECT i.*
FROM item i
JOIN (
    SELECT
    MAX(ITEMID) AS max_id
    FROM 
    item
    GROUP BY Name
) si ON i.ITEMID = si.max_id;
```

Here are more examples of how to get **[The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html)**.

**The final query is**

```
SELECT TAGID, tag.NAME, RATE, COALESCE(ITEM_QTY, 0) AS ITEM_QTY
FROM
tag
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT i.*
    FROM item i
    JOIN (
        SELECT
        MAX(ITEMID) AS max_id
        FROM 
        item
        GROUP BY Name
    ) si ON i.ITEMID = si.max_id
) items ON tag.Name = items.Name
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d7dd/4/0)